# trying to change the value of a variable in console but it's coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript

Ok so I am pretty new to using javascript (most of my experience is in python) and am trying to change the value of a variable for a timer called timer in the console, the code is:

```
function f(timer) {
    var timer = 120000;
  return timer
}
```

It is coming up as undefined and it does nothing to the value of the timer variable I'd appreciate help on what I am doing wrong thanks in advance.

Ok I did forget to execute f() and the function f(timer) should have been f() however the main problem is that although I thought timer was a variable (timer already existed as 2000) it was actually a const, is there a way to turn it into a variable or possibly change the 2000 from miliseconds to something larger to increase time or temporarily stop the timer for more time to increase to that point? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You need to execute it `f()`. You functions works fine in my console.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As stated above, you need to call `f()`, but I'm not sure if that's your problem.  I think we need more details on what you're doing.  How is `f()` being called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variable in the global scope and not just in the scope of `f()`.

Try this and it'll work just fine:

```
var timer
function f() {
    timer = 120000;
    return timer
}

f()
console.log(timer)
```

If you want to change the value based on an argument you can do that:

```
var timer
function f(newValue) {
    timer = newValue;
    return timer
}

f(120000)
console.log(timer)
```

Comment: Typically, isn't code improved when things are moving *out of global scope*?